# Why can I initialize the size of an array by taking user input in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-length-array

**Given that user input is taken at runtime but array is created during compile time. How and why does this piece of code work?**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n]; //Why can I use this statement to create an array?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a non-standard extension, supported by gcc and clang.

It works by allocating space on the stack at the point the array is declared, a bit like [`alloca`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html).

The memory allocated is automatically freed (by adjusting the stack pointer) when the function returns (or `arr` goes out of scope).